# How many pairs of clock hands?

Tags: combinatorics

An (imaginary) company producing parlor games for children wants to produce a novel game with pairs of clock hands. Each pair can be fixed at certain non-zero angles and must be placed on a clock face to point at two numbers. At each round player One sets a pair at some angle and player Two must put it on the clock face such that no number is pointed at twice. To this end player Two may consider relocating some of the earlier pairs without changing the fixed angle. The game ends when player Two got stuck or placed all pairs.
The game must be produced for several levels: e.g. a $12$-hours clock for beginners and a $24$-hours clock for advanced players. Aiming at low prices, how many pairs of hands must at least be included in the package for each level?

In mathematical terms, the question may be phrased like this:

Given an integer $n$ (e.g., $n = 12$, or $n = 24$, or whatever), what is the maximal number $b$ such that $b$ pairs of (distinct) vertices can *always* be rotated apart in a regular $n$-gon.

Note the word "always". By way of illustration, it is sometimes possible to locate n/2 pairs with *all different* angles up to a stretched angle, which is a specification of the pairs. (The phenomenon happens for $n$ of type $8$-fold or $8$-fold plus $2$, and only for these.) So, the company is not inclined to include up to $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ pairs of hands.

I found that
$$b = \left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
n/3 & n \text{ a multiple of } 3 \\
\lceil (n+2)/3 \rceil & \text{otherwise}
\end{array} \right.$$
is sharp for $n \leq 12$,  for $n$ a multiple of $3$, and for $n = 14, 20$,
but not otherwise in case $n \leq 32$. Part of this knowledge was obtained with computer assistance.

I think that problems of this type should be settled by reasoning alone. Anyone?

NB: $\lceil x \rceil$ and $\lfloor x \rfloor$ denote upper- and lower integer approximation of a real number $x$.